# How to implement Tensorflow's depecrated tf.range_input_producer function with tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to implement word embedding using Tensorflow based on their official website's RNN tutorial with Jupyter Notebook.

Based on the [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py), a function called `ptb_producer` is responsible for converting the text data (which already converted into ids) to batches and outputs a tuple of inputs and labels. In the function, tensorflow's `range_input_producer` is responsible for outputs the integers from `0` to `limit-1` in a queue on the number of epochs.

```
epoch_size = (batch_len - 1) // num_steps
    assertion = tf.assert_positive(
        epoch_size,
        message="epoch_size == 0, decrease batch_size or num_steps")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
      epoch_size = tf.identity(epoch_size, name="epoch_size")

    i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
```

But if try to put the set the outputs of `ptb_producer` function into a tuple of variables, take one of the element (let say the input) of the tuple and get the embedding for that element (the input), the process paused in Jupyter Notebook.

```
inputs, targets = ptb_producer(train_data, 32, 1, name="TrainStep")

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embeddings = tf.get_variable("embeddings", [10000, 300], dtype=tf.float32)
    new_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputs)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(new_inputs)
```

When I try to run `sess.run(new_inputs)`, the notebook paused and nothing is being outputted to the notebook. I also tried to run`sess.run((init, new_inputs))`, but the notebook also paused.

A warning from Tensorflow stated that `tf.train.range_input_producer` is deprecated and it is better for me to use `tf.data.Dataset.range(limit).shuffle(limit).repeat(num_epochs).  If shuffle=False, omit the .shuffle(...)`.

I expected that it will return the same tuple of inputs and targets. But when I tried it, it seems that `tf.data.Dataset` does not return an integer.

```
epoch_size = (batch_len - 1) // num_steps
    assertion = tf.assert_positive(
        epoch_size,
        message="epoch_size == 0, decrease batch_size or num_steps")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
      epoch_size = tf.identity(epoch_size, name="epoch_size")
      epoch_size = tf.cast(epoch_size, tf.int64)

    i = tf.data.Dataset.range(epoch_size).repeat()
```

Outputs

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2007122212cd> in <module>
----> 1 inputs, targets = ptb_producer(train_data[:1000], 32, 1, name="TrainStep")

<ipython-input-11-2a2491970140> in ptb_producer(raw_data, batch_size, num_steps, name)
     31 
     32     i = tf.data.Dataset.range(epoch_size).repeat()
---> 33     x = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps],
     34                          [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps])
     35     x.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'RepeatDataset' and 'int'
```

Again, my attempt is to be able to see the embedding of each word. I was wondering if there was something I missed?

Comment: I think you need to define an iterator and get the elements from the iterator. For example i = tf.data.Dataset.range(epoch_size).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

Comment: Wow that worked really well, Thank you!